# How to use nested and referenced data on Aggregation Mongodb, Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 following models: Study, WordSet and Category.

**As you can see Study model has reference into WordSet, then WordSet has reference into Category.**

And my problem is that i don't know how to refer into Category from Study.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
exports.getStats = async (req, res) => {
        const stats = await Study.aggregate([
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              learnedWordSet: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'WordSet',
              localField: 'learnedWordSet',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'wordSet',
            },
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: null, // calculate for all
              category: '$learnedWordSet.category'
            },
          },
        ]);
    };
```

Study

```
const studySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
          name: {
            type: String,
          },
          learnedWordSet: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'WordSet',
          },
        });
```

WordSet

```
const wordSetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      category: {
        type: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
            required: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

Category

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

Comment: You cannot go directly into `Category` from `Study`; you have to go through `WordSet`.    You simply need a second `$lookup`.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti could you write it to me how it should like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interpretation of the study/wordset/category data.  I have used simpler types for the `_id` of the collections so as not to get the output full of distracting string representations of ObjectId e.g. `ObjectId("61cf5305ce7708767e8d490c")`

```
var r = [
    { _id:"S0", name:"studyA", learnedWordSet:"W1"},
    { _id:"S1", name:"studyA", learnedWordSet:"W2"},
    { _id:"S2", name:"studyB", learnedWordSet:"W1"},
    { _id:"S3", name:"studyB", learnedWordSet:"W3"},
];
db.study.insert(r);

var r = [
    { _id:"W1", name:"wordset1", category: [ "C1", "C2" ] },
    { _id:"W2", name:"wordset2", category: [ "C3" ] },
    { _id:"W3", name:"wordset3", category: [ "C1", "C3" ] }
];
db.wordset.insert(r);

var r = [
    { _id:"C1", name:"category1"},
    { _id:"C2", name:"category2"},
    { _id:"C3", name:"category3"}
];
db.category.insert(r);
```

Here is a "double lookup" that takes advantage of the newer form of `$lookup` that can process a pipeline that itself contains a `$lookup`.

```
db.study.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "wordset",
               let: { wid: "$learnedWordSet" },
               pipeline: [
                   {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$wid" ]} }},
                   {$lookup: {"from": "category",
                              let: { cids: "$category" },
                              pipeline: [
                                  // The Juice!  The pipeline lookup can use                        
                                  // nice expressions like inlists ($in):                           
                                  {$match: {$expr: {$in: [ "$_id", "$$cids" ]} }}
                              ],
                              as: "category" // replace orig fld with lookup info                   
                             }},
               ],
               as: "learnedWordSet"
              }}
    // we know learnedWordSet is 1:1 so "lift" array[0] out and                                     
    // make it the only single object:                                                              
    ,{$addFields: {learnedWordSet: {$arrayElemAt: ["$learnedWordSet",0]}} }

]);
```

This will yield output like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "S0",
    "name" : "studyA",
    "learnedWordSet" : {
        "_id" : "W1",
        "name" : "wordset1",
        "category" : [
            {
                "_id" : "C1",
                "name" : "category1"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "C2",
                "name" : "category2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "S1",
    "name" : "studyA",
    "learnedWordSet" : {
        "_id" : "W2",
        "name" : "wordset2",
        "category" : [
            {
                "_id" : "C3",
                "name" : "category3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortanetly  the second $lookup doesn't work for me. Data isn't populated on response. I must mention that i created that topic with 'cropped' models. Few days ago i created this one but nobody answered for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533053/how-to-make-aggregation-and-group-by-specific-condition-in-mongoose-node-js. Could you look at it and help me to manage that?